# How to add a 'or' condition in #ifdef

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

How can I add a 'or' condition in #ifdef ?

I have tried:

```c
#ifdef CONDITION1 || CONDITION2

#endif
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

```
#if defined(CONDITION1) || defined(CONDITION2)
```

should work. :)

`#ifdef` is a bit less typing, but doesn't work well with more complex conditions

Comment: What if I want to add this condition in else part `#elif` ?

Comment: @iEngineer `#elif defined(CONDITION1) || defined(CONDITION2)`?

Comment: how to use #ifndef with multiple condition?

Comment: @user3017748 #if !defined(CONDITION1) || !defined(CONDITION2)

Comment: @user3017748, jalf's comment works if you want something to happen if *either* of the two conditions are *not* defined. If you want it to happen if *neither of them are defined*, you'd use an AND: `#if !defined(CONDITION1) && !defined(CONDITION2)`.

Comment: Does this not need an `#endif`?

Comment: I believe it does require `#endif`, @Stevoisiak.

Answer (score 55):

May use this-

```
#if defined CONDITION1 || defined CONDITION2
//your code here
#endif
```

This also does the same-

```
#if defined(CONDITION1) || defined(CONDITION2)
//your code here
#endif
```

---

**Further-**

- AND: `#if defined CONDITION1 && defined CONDITION2`
- XOR: `#if defined CONDITION1 ^ defined CONDITION2`
- AND NOT: `#if defined CONDITION1 && !defined CONDITION2`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    #if defined __WINDOWS__ && ( _MSC_VER >= 1700 )
        enum class FUTURES_DS_STAGE{
            ...
        };
    #else
        enum FUTURES_DS_STAGE{
        ...
        };
    #endif
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question *"How to add a 'or' condition in #ifdef?"* Please avoid code only answers, especially if you try to address the question indirectly.

Answer (score -7):

I am really OCD about maintaining **strict column limits**, and not a fan of "\"
line continuation because you can't put a comment after it, so here is my method.

```
//|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|//
#ifdef  CONDITION_01             //|       |//
#define             TEMP_MACRO   //|       |//
#endif                           //|       |//
#ifdef  CONDITION_02             //|       |//
#define             TEMP_MACRO   //|       |//
#endif                           //|       |//
#ifdef  CONDITION_03             //|       |//
#define             TEMP_MACRO   //|       |//
#endif                           //|       |//
#ifdef              TEMP_MACRO   //|       |//
//|-  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -|//

printf("[IF_CONDITION:(1|2|3)]\n");

//|-  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  -|//
#endif                           //|       |//
#undef              TEMP_MACRO   //|       |//
//|________________________________________|//
```

Comment: oh that's naaasty...