# check macro OR true condition in #ifdef

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm developing a c++ library used by two applications, let's call them *App1* and *App2*. I'm the developer of *App1* too.

I would like to develop a new feature in the library used after deployment by *App2*, that is fully compatible with *App1*; even if I don't want to include it since it will cause my application to link against other libraries. I wish to have a more lightweight executable.

While developing this feature, I have to write in many part of the library something like this:

```
#ifdef FEATURE_APP_2
    ...
#endif
```

The problem is that while developing, the IDE (VS2013) "disables" the code between the `#ifdef` and `#endif` so I cannot benefit from intellisense or compiler checks.

So I was thinking about a double check like the following, read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998864/how-to-add-a-or-condition-in-ifdef):

```
#if defined(FEATURE_APP_2) || defined (1)
    ...
#endif
```

Once everything is written, compiled and tested I can simply find and replace the `#if defined(FEATURE_APP_2) || defined (1)` with just `#if defined(FEATURE_APP_2)`.

The problem is that the statement:

```
#if defined(FEATURE_APP_2) || defined (1)
```

is not accepted.

So the question is how can I OR a "real" macro and a "fake" TRUE macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer literal `1` is not a macro that is defined or not, which is what `defined` checks for. Instead use just plain `1`, as in

```
#if defined(FEATURE_APP_2) || 1
...
#endif
```

---

That said I would not really recommend the solution you have, not even after my fix, since it is much to easy to forget to remove one `|| 1` somewhere.

Instead you could have a new macro that you check, like

```
#if defined(FEATURE_APP_2) || defined(ENABLE_ALL_FEATURES)
...
#endif
```

Then when developing you define `ENABLE_ALL_FEATURES` for the project, and undefine it when building the release.

Comment: You answered my implicit question too